# How do combine a count in a particular select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

On our postgresql database we currently have 2 tables called Users and Bookings.

We are currently trying to know on the users that made a booking yesterday how many bookings they did over time.

Here is the query we have for the moment:

```
SELECT "domain".users.email, COUNT("domain".bookings."id")
FROM "domain".bookings
INNER JOIN "domain".users ON "domain".users."id" = "domain".bookings.user_id
GROUP BY "domain".users.email
```

If we have the date the booking was created (field "domain.bookings.created_at) with filter yesterday we only get the data from yesterday.

Is there a way to see on who bought yesterday how many bookings they did overtime?

Thank you!
Luca

Comment: Add `count(case when bookingdate = yesterday then 1 end)` (pseudo SQL) to  the select list.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output. I don't really understand what output you expect

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT "domain".users.email, COUNT(CASE WHEN bookingdate = current_date - 1 THEN 1 END ) AS TOTAL_BOOKING
FROM "domain".bookings
INNER JOIN "domain".users ON "domain".users."id" = "domain".bookings.user_id
GROUP BY "domain".users.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering. I was probably not precise enough!

Basically if I use the following query:

```
SELECT
"domain".users.email,
COUNT( "domain".bookings."id") AS "Total Bookings"
FROM
"domain".bookings
INNER JOIN "domain".users ON "domain".users."id" = "domain".bookings.user_id    
GROUP BY
"domain".users.email
```

I get the number of bookings made by a user.

BUT

I want to get the following: the number of bookings made all time by the users that bought yesterday.

I tried this

```
SELECT
"domain".users.email,
COUNT( "domain".bookings."id") AS "Total Bookings"
FROM
"domain".bookings
INNER JOIN "domain".users ON "domain".users."id" = "domain".bookings.user_id    
WHERE
"domain".bookings.created_at = 'yesterday'
GROUP BY
"domain".users.email
```

But I am getting no responses...

Thank you for help!

Luca

Comment: Don't add additional information as an answer [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37522512/edit) your question instead.

Comment: Ok sorry... Quite new with all this!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, count(b.id) AS "Total Bookings" 
FROM "domain".bookings as b
  JOIN "domain".users as U ON u.id = b.user_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM "domain".bookings b2
              WHERE b2.created_at = current_date - 1
                AND b2.user_id = b.user_id)
GROUP BY u.email;
```

The exists condition will only return rows from the `bookings` table for users that booked something yesterday.

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: using a keyword like `domain` that requires double quotes for identifiers is not such a good idea. It would save you some trouble in the long run if you found a different name</sup>

Comment: Thank you!  I tested but I am still getting the numbers for all users, it looks like the filter is not working...

Query is:

SELECT 
"domain".users."id", 
"domain".users.email, 
count("domain".bookings."id") AS "Total Bookings" 
FROM "domain".bookings 
JOIN "domain".users ON "domain".users."id" = "domain".bookings.user_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
       FROM "domain".bookings
              WHERE "domain".bookings.created_at < current_date - 1
                AND "domain".bookings.user_id = "domain".bookings.user_id)
GROUP BY 
"domain".users.email,
"domain".users."id"